# Convert this date/time into actual date/time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following date/time string imported into a cell in Excel.

```
25 Oct 2016 05:46AM
```

I need to have this converted into a proper date/time that Excel understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DATEVALUE function:

```
=DATEVALUE("25 Oct 2016 05:46AM")
```

For example, if your date string is contained in cell `A1`:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)
```